# CefSharp minimal example - A blank window shows/disappears

Tags: cefsharp

I haven't seen any posts concerning this, so perhaps someone can help.

On the minimal example, A blank window opens and immediately disappears only on the first opening of the browser. I'd like a way to suppress this behavior.

To reproduce, change this line of code in the Winforms example:

browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("www.foxnews.com")

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd be surprised if it's actually blank, likely says not sandboxed, record and slow down the playback, then search for the message.

Comment: Thanks for your help... It appears the problem is with my development machine. Loaded it in Virtual PC, no problems... Thanks again. I really appreciate the answers given here.

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1259 is the likely cause of the window